# pagination not working properly in searching

Tags: php, search, pagination

I have created some code of searching and pagination in it. If a user wants to search using some industry then data is shown against it. But whenever he presses any option in the pagination then it shows all the data related to every industry. How can i show pagination related to search result. And if user has selected any industry then it should be selected if user move to page 2 or page 3 or any.

**Code of page**

```
            <?php 
        $pd=(isset($script['details']) ? $script['details']:array()) ;
        //jobs search and normal page view
        $qstr=Querystring();  
        $obj_pagination = new Pagination();  
        $obj_pagination->limit = (($FP_LIMIT!="") ? $FP_LIMIT:10);
        $pagid=1; 
        if(isset($qstr["page"])) {
            $pagid=$qstr["page"]; 
        }
        $obj_pagination->page = $pagid; 
        $srcqry="";
        $industry=0;
        if(isset($_POST['industry'])){
            if(isset($_POST['industry'])){
                if($_POST['industry']!="0") {
                    $srcqry=$srcqry." AND j.industry ='".(int)$_POST['industry']."'";
                    $industry=(int)$_POST['industry'];
                }
            }
            $nrs = $obj->query("SELECT * FROM jobs j WHERE j.status='1' ".$srcqry); 
        } else {
            $nrs = $obj->query("SELECT * FROM jobs j WHERE j.status='1' ".$srcqry); 
        } 
        $tot_rec= count($nrs->rows);
        $obj_pagination->total = $tot_rec;
        $obj_pagination->url = "jobs?page={page}";
        $num_pages = ceil($obj_pagination->total / $obj_pagination->limit);
        $start = ($obj_pagination->page-1)*$obj_pagination->limit;
        $end = $obj_pagination->limit;
        $limit = "LIMIT $start,$end"; 
        $check;
         ?>
        <h3>Search</h3>
              <form name="srchjobs" action="/jobs" method="post">
              <div class="col1">
                  <select class="dropdown1 spacer_side" name="industry"> 
                        <option value="0">All Industries</option>
                        <?php $indrow=getAllIndustries(); 
                        if(count($indrow) > 0) {  
                           foreach($indrow as $tr) {?>
                               <option value="<?php echo $tr['id']; ?>" <?php if($tr['id']==$industry) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $tr['name']; ?></option>
                               <?php   } 
                               $check=$tr['name']; 
                               } 
                               ?>  
                   </select>
               </div>   
               <button type='submit'>Search</button>
               </form>
        <?php
            $indrow=getAllIndustries();
            $sql="SELECT j.*,u.url FROM jobs as j, aliases as u WHERE j.status='1' ".$srcqry." 
            AND (j.id=u.slog_id AND u.slog='jobs') ORDER BY j.id DESC ".$limit;
            $jresults = $obj->query($sql);
            if($jresults->rows) { 
                foreach($jresults->rows as $j){
                    $empd=array();
                    $empd=getIndinfo($j['industry']);
                    $emplogo="/uploads/no-image.png";
                    ?>
                    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="<?php echo $emplogo;?>" alt="dell1" height="66" width="66" /></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $j['url']; ?>"><h5><?php echo $j['title']; ?></h5></a>
                    <a href="/job-apply?id=<?php echo $j['id'];?>" class="appler" value="">APPLY</a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <?php
                            $obj_pagination->text_next = "&#62;";
                            $obj_pagination->text_prev = "&#60;";
                            $obj_pagination->text_first = "&#171;";
                            $obj_pagination->text_last = "&#187;";
                            $obj_pagination->text = "Showing {start} to {end} of {total}";
                            echo $obj_pagination->render();
                    ?></ul>
                     <?php } else { ?>
                              <span class="latest_job">No jobs Found</span> 
             <?php } ?>
```

**querystring function code**

```
  function Querystring(){
    $_G=array();
    $REQUEST_URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $REQUEST_URI_ARR = explode("?",$REQUEST_URI);
    $REQUEST_URI_ARR_All =  explode("&",$REQUEST_URI_ARR[1]); 
    foreach($REQUEST_URI_ARR_All as $key=>$val){
            $gs = explode("=",$val);
            if(isset($gs[0]) && isset($gs[1]))
                            $_G[$gs[0]] = urldecode($gs[1]);
    } 
    return $_G; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Output your results in a table and just use a jquery enabled table class. That way pagination will be automatic. Ensure you have a  tag as well.

Comment: any idea about the method above

Comment: Just do it in your foreach loop. `foreach($results as $r){
echo $r['id'];
}`

Comment: `foreach($indrow as $tr) {?>
                               <option value="<?php echo $tr['id']; ?>" <?php if($tr['id']==$industry) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $tr['name']; ?></option>
                               <?php   } 
                               $check=$tr['name']; 
                               } 
                               ?>`

Comment: which portion should i do in this

Comment: Just convert what you have to a table output instead of text

Comment: I've helped you as much as I can